# clojure list manipulation multilist to list

Tags: clojure, list-manipulation

Is there a clojure function to do:

```
((1 2) (3) (5 1) (2)) => (1 2 3 5 1 2)

(def a-list '((1 2) (3) (5 1) (2)))
(my-func a-list)
   ;; =>(1 2 3 5 1 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(flatten a-list)
```

will do the trick as well.

See:
http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/apply
http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/concat
http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/flatten

Answer (score 4):

```
(apply concat a-list) ;; (1 2 3 5 1 2)
```